# How do i make the header normal size. CSS GRID

Tags: html, css

How would I make the header full width? And I would like the content class to the right, and the skills class to the right 30% to 70%. If you are able to understand the issue I wasn't able to figure out please tell me what you did to get it to work. Thanks.

I couldn't find any info on how to make the header full width, and move the content to other spots...

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0px;
}

body {
 background-image: url("coder.jpeg");
 background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
 grid-template-rows: ;
 grid-gap: 10px;
}

.header {
 background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.99);
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.skills {
 background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.99);
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.content {
 background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.99);
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Cl32</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header">
    <header>
     <h1>Cdad</h1>
    </header>
   </div>

   <div class="skills">
    <aside>
     <h2>Skills</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla fuga asperiores iusto eveniet aliquid nobis aliquam ducimus, tempora consequatur neque earum molestiae unde porro, quis numquam error illum temporibus, incidunt autem. Temporibus maxime esse magnam inventore odit vero in quae sit quo laboriosam? Architecto saepe repudiandae ducimus possimus magni numquam?</p>
    </aside>
   </div>

   <div class="content">
    <h2>yuyuyggoggo</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum mollitia sunt at aliquid unde vel sapiente quas sequi repudiandae, quam facere inventore suscipit sed nam quae possimus reprehenderit doloremque. Reprehenderit nisi architecto vel molestiae placeat necessitatibus deleniti laborum facere unde itaque magnam amet ut aspernatur distinctio atque ad perspiciatis nam beatae fugiat illum error veritatis, cupiditate odit? Deserunt earum magni id animi, temporibus sit obcaecati ipsum. Blanditiis, expedita? Fugit dicta ex dignissimos, esse totam voluptas illo maxime minus quae nisi velit nemo sequi nulla et omnis deserunt nam sed ducimus. Minima animi dolor vitae architecto suscipit ipsa eaque autem incidunt.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!--warpper class ends-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I understand your question correctly but if you add `grid-column: 1  / span 2;`to your header class it will give you full width.

Comment: thanks that worked.. is there any difference with doing ur grid-column:1 / span 2; few mins ago i found out that grid-column-start: 1  grid-column-end:3 does the same thing.

Comment: The grid-column is shorthand for grid-column-start and grid-column-end ... you can read more about it in below link. And also. Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you ;) 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column